# IntelliJ Idea: how to dock the java-doc window

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc

how can we dock the [java-doc window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/documentation-tool-window.html) to the IntelliJ IDE?
There is no `Docked mode` in the window-popup like explained in the [IDE help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/viewing-modes.html#ways_to_control)

e.g. it should be like the Structure, Messages, Version Control tool Window.

Comment: Screenshot, please?

Comment: I have the same problem in mac intellij, and don't know how to dock it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is something wrong with this window: by default it shows up in your face, preventing you from getting any work done, and it is not immediately obvious how to dismiss it.  A programmer's first encounter with this window tends to be a rather bad user experience.

The way I dismiss it is as follows:

- Click on the gray gear menu (the one at the top, not the blue one right below it)
- Uncheck *Floating mode*. It will then obtain a "Docked Mode" option.
- Move it to any side you like; it will then stay there.

Comment: I hope someone from JetBrains is listening.  (They usually do here.)

Comment: Oh: now it works: I thought that `Floating Mode` and `Windowed Mode` work like radio boxes. I didn't think that I can deactivate both.

Comment: Just spent 15 minutes clicking furiously on floating and windowed mode...